# Mensa Workout Quiz question - letter series

Tags: pattern, sequence, letter-sequence

I took the [Mensa Workout Quiz](https://www.mensa.org/node/452/take/1) and I wasn't able to do this letter series question:

> Which letter comes next in this series of letters? B A C B D C E D F ?

The options given were:

> C, D, E and F

Despite trying multiple ways, I wasn't able to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> E

Because:

> The pattern goes like this: -1 then + 2, -1 then +2 and so on. Hence, the answer is E.